# splitting parameters in a string with parenthesis

Tags: c++, c++03

I'd like to find an efficient way to split this kind of string and store the parameters in variables:

```
param1 (param2 param3) (param4 param5) ... param6
```

example:

```
1.  (10 10) (10 15) (2 11) 2.
1.  (12 20) 2.
```

(there is an undefined number of parenthesis containing each 2 numbers separated by a space)

I have to store the first and last parameters in a double, and the numbers in parenthesis in vector.

for the second example it would give:

```
double beginOfLine, endOfLine
vector<int> vec1;
vector<int> vec2;
beginOfLine = 1.;
endOfLine = 2.;
vec1.push_back(12);
vec2.push_back(20);
```

I find it very easy in python. But in C++ i'm unable to do it in a simple way.

nb: I'm not allowed to use boost/C++11 and later

Comment: And now you will say, you can't use boost as well ?

Comment: no I can't use boost

Comment: With the example "input" you show, what should the output be? How should the "input" be split?

Comment: Please show the python code that you wrote for this.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you aren't allowed to use C++11. std::regex could have made this a short program.

Comment: I doesn't understood what are you want.

Comment: In the `<complex>` header there is an `operator>>` that can read values in the format `(12,20)`. You might get some inspiration from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use C++11, then some basic string spliting with `std::stringstream` might do the job. I'm not sure whenever `<limits>` is part of C++11, but you can easily replace them with another maximum value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    double beginOfLine = 0.0, endOfLine = 0.0;
    std::vector<int> vec1;
    std::vector<int> vec2;

    std::stringstream ss("1.  (10 10) (10 15) (2 11) 2.");

    ss >> beginOfLine;

    while (true) {
        int first, second;
        ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '(');
        ss >> first >> second;
        vec1.push_back(first);
        vec2.push_back(second);
        ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ')');
        ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ' ');

        if (ss.peek() != '(') {
            ss >> endOfLine;
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << beginOfLine << '\n';
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec1.begin(); it != vec1.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec2.begin(); it != vec2.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n' << endOfLine;
    return 0;
}
```